# index ListView.builder always return 0

Tags: flutter, dart

Why index  ListView.builder always return 0, when I click checkbox. It is because of I'm using `child: ListView.builder()` or another issue.

Below is my issue code

```
final _data = List<dynamic>.generate(30, (i) => CheckBoxModel(isChecked: false, count: 1));

Container(
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: < Widget > [
            SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
                width: 50.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Checkbox(
                            checkColor: Colors.white,
                            value: _data[index].isChecked,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                    _data[index].isChecked = value;
                                });
                                print(index);
                            },
                        );
                    }),
            ),
        ],
    ))
```

CheckBoxModel Code

```
class CheckBoxModel {
  bool isChecked = false;
  int count = 0;
  CheckBoxModel({this.isChecked, count});
}
```

And when I increase width sizeBox it display like image bellow

[image]

Comment: Please include `_data`

Comment: I've include _data

Comment: what happens when you `print(index)`?

Comment: always print `0`

Answer (score 0):

If the index is `0`, it means the first. Sample code:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
  
  print(list[0]); // First
  print(list[1]); // Second
  print(list[2]); // Third
}
```

If it just prints `0` (no other numbers), I think it's because there is only one item in the `_data` list.

Comment: when put `print(_data)` display like this..


`[Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel', Instance of 'CheckBoxModel',   ...`

Comment: And when I `print(_data.length);` it return `30`

Comment: @Fash can you share the code for `CheckBoxModel`?